# requirements.txt bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: django, pip

I'm working on a github repo which I just cloned. I have a new virtual environment and I'd like to add all of the packages from the requirements.txt file to the virtual env.

For some reason it is not finding my requirements.txt file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: the requirements file seems to be in the right place (in the root of a repository). What happen if you copy the requirements in the venv and use the pip command ?

Comment: That gives me the same error message

Comment: Actually any pip install commands return that error

Comment: Run `which pip` and ensure that it's pointing to the pip in your venv. You've got things setup different to how I normally do. I normally create an env, then clone in to the env directory.

Comment: I'm coming up with the following: (venv)Robs-MacBook-Pro:venv byrd$ which pip
/Users/byrd/Desktop/Github Repositories/herokusite/venv/bin/pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the first line of `/Users/byrd/Desktop/Github Repositories/herokusite/venv/bin/pip` file to correct the path to `python`.  You can obtain this path by calling `which python`. I think it should be:

```
#!/Users/byrd/Desktop/Github\ Repositories/herokusite/venv/bin/python
```

**EDIT**: Seems like it is a known bug in unixes - you [can't use spaces in shebang line](http://stevesmithbytes.blogspot.ru/2011/02/handling-spaces-in-shebang-line-in-mac.html).

Also try this [workaround](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/923#issuecomment-33002478), it may help you.

Comment: This is the first line of the file: #!"/Users/byrd/Desktop/Github Repositories/herokusite/venv/bin/python2.7"

Comment: Remove the `"` quotes from this string and escape the space with a backslash as I did in my answer.

Comment: For some reason it returned the same result

Comment: Show the output of `which python` and show the exact edited first line from `pip`.  Did you escaped the space symbol?

Comment: Here is which python: /Users/byrd/Desktop/Github Repositories/herokusite/venv/bin/python

Comment: Here is the pip line: #!/Users/byrd/Desktop/Github\ Repositories/herokusite/venv/bin/python2.7

Comment: Try to remove "2.7" from shebang line.

Comment: What happens then you type `/Users/byrd/Desktop/Github\ Repositories/herokusite/venv/bin/python` and command line and press "Return"?

Comment: That puts me into the python interpreter

Comment: The last thing I can imagine is the wrong newline at the end of shebang. Place the cursor right after the `python` name and press "Return" to be sure that there is no additional spaces and newline symbol is correct for MacOS.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I'll be sure to comment when I get it sorted out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I replaced the space with an underscore and that seemed to solve the issue. For some reason the space was throwing it off and the \ didn't seem to escape it.

Comment: Seems like it is known bug of Mac OS: http://stevesmithbytes.blogspot.ru/2011/02/handling-spaces-in-shebang-line-in-mac.html

Comment: Look at this conversation and workaround: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/923#issuecomment-33002478

Answer (score 0):

Do not use spaces in any component of the path where your virtual environment is stored.

It causes problems for the bootstrapping process.

Create a new blank environment, in a directory that has no spaces in its path:

```
$ cd  # this takes you to your home directory, in OSX its is /Users/yourlogin
$ cd Desktop
$ virtualenv myvenv
$ source myvenv/bin/activate
(myvenv) $ pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

first, execute `which pip` after activating the environment if you found a space between any of the folders like 
[as seen in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IEsQ.png)

you must have noticed a space between the folder name

> 2nd july

next, delete the new virualenv (in my case envname) and rename the folder with space between its name

then create a new virual environment and then install the requirements through

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

on the folder location with the requirements file